# Unknown provider: $resourceProvider after bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have af MVC 4.5 project with angularjs. I have done bundle and minification on controllers and factories. I have read about making angular controllers and factory minification safe, but I get this error and I cant find the problem:

> Unknown provider: $resourceProvider

The Module:

```
var app = angular.module("seducApp", []);
app.$inject = ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.tinymce', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip',
'mgcrea.ngStrap.datepicker', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.alert', 'ui.select', 'uuid4', 'rt.popup', 'angular-md5', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.button',
'ui.bootstrap.tabs', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.timepicker', 'naif.base64', 'base64', 'angular-smilies', 'angular-google-adsense',
'angularFileUpload', 'angular.directives-round-progress', 'numericbinding', 'ngImgCrop', 'ui.tree', 'timer',
'$httpProviderConfig', '$compileProviderConfig', '$locationProviderConfig', 'uiSelectConfig', 'datetimeFilter',
'cutFilter', 'groupFilter', 'partitionFilter', 'aDisabledDirective'];
```

The Factory:

```
app.factory('siteRepository', function ($resource, $http) {
   return {
        checkSiteStatus: function () {
            return $resource('/Home/GetSiteStatus').query();
        },
        getSiteStatus: function () { 
            return $http.get('/Home/GetSiteStatus') 
        },        
        getSiteChangeLog: function () {
            return $http.get('/Home/GetSiteChangeLog')
        }
    }
});
```

Debug is set to true in web.config, then I should not get the minified version of the factory.

I have tried a great number of things, but no solutions :(

Comment: have you verified you're actually not getting a minified file?

Comment: All files in the bundle are not minified. If debug ist set to true in Web.config, then the noneminified version is included. Or is there at way to se or test this?

Comment: view the source of the page and look for the js file...

Comment: It is the none minified versions there are included..

Comment: are you sure you are including the ng-resource script file as well?

Comment: Yes, this is included: "~/Scripts/angular-resource.js",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `app.$inject` statement. Instead, pass a dependency array. Observe the following simplified demo which demonstrates this a bit...

```
var mod = angular.module('mod', []);

mod.factory('modFactory', function() {

    return {
        'woo': function woo() {
            console.log('woah!');
        }
    }
});

// -----------------------------------------------------

var app = angular.module('app', ['mod']);

app.controller('ctrl', function(modFactory) {
    modFactory.woo();
});
```

The above works while the following will fail...

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.$inject = ['mod'];
```

> Unknown provider: modFactoryProvider

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/5sfykdvv/) - demo

---

A quick fix on your issue would include changing you `app` definition to the following...

```
var app = angular.module('seducApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.tinymce', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip',
'mgcrea.ngStrap.datepicker', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.alert', 'ui.select', 'uuid4', 'rt.popup', 'angular-md5', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.button',
'ui.bootstrap.tabs', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.timepicker', 'naif.base64', 'base64', 'angular-smilies', 'angular-google-adsense',
'angularFileUpload', 'angular.directives-round-progress', 'numericbinding', 'ngImgCrop', 'ui.tree', 'timer',
'$httpProviderConfig', '$compileProviderConfig', '$locationProviderConfig', 'uiSelectConfig', 'datetimeFilter',
'cutFilter', 'groupFilter', 'partitionFilter', 'aDisabledDirective']);
```

Check out the [Angular DI docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for more details on the topic

Comment: Right angular document only mention $inject on controller/service/directive etc, but not on modules

Comment: @Okazari I saw that as well, though I couldn't find any details on injecting modules. Perhaps it's not possible, but it's a guess at this point

Comment: I guess it's because inject will find and get the dependency and will then inject it in a function. But a module is actually not a function unlike controllers/directive etc...

Comment: This seems to solved the problem. Thanks. That saved the day :)

Comment: Now I get a Error: [ng:areq] on the controllers, when I turn debug to false in web.config..

Comment: @AHJ probably now you're getting minified files, just re-write your factory the "min safe" way. You should be writing all of your controllers, services, and factories this way anyways e.g. `app.factory('siteRepository', ['$resource', '$http', function ($resource, $http) { /*...*/ }]);`

Answer (score 0):

First could you try this piece of code ?

```
app.factory('siteRepository',['$resource','$http', function ($resource, $http) {
   return {
    checkSiteStatus: function () {
        return $resource('/Home/GetSiteStatus').query();
    },
    getSiteStatus: function () { 
        return $http.get('/Home/GetSiteStatus') 
    },        
    getSiteChangeLog: function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetSiteChangeLog')
    }
  }
}]);
```

If this work, you have a classic trouble with minification and injection.

I suggest you to look at https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate or to rewrite all your injection syntax in your application (with the array of dependency names)

Let me know if it helped and/or if you need more help about this.